# Torsion in the first cohomology of a lattice in a semisimple Lie group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, lattices

Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact lattice in a complex semisimple Lie group $G$ of dimension $n$. Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}\Gamma$-module, finitely generated as an abelian group (let $r$ be the minimal number of generators). Then the first cohomology $H^1(\Gamma, M)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. Is it possible to bound the order of the torsion subgroup of $H^1(\Gamma, M)$ by a function of $n$ and $r$? Or by a function of $n$, $r$ and some numerical invariants of $\Gamma$?